# Split odd numbered list into even columns

Tags: multicolumn

I am trying to split 5 items list into two columns, but the second column only write on the 1st and the 3rd line.[image: here]. Do't know how to solve this, and how can i change the space between the two columns?.

```
\begin{enumerate}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\item Delta (0.5 - 4 Hz)
\item Theta (4 - 8 Hz)
\item Alpha (8 - 13 Hz)
\item Beta (13 - 22 Hz)
\item Gamma (30 - 40 Hz)
\end{multicols}
\end{enumerate}
```

Comment: It would look better with a horizontal enumeration, as obtained with the `tasks` or `shortlst` packages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`multicols` by default tries to balance the columns; that is, it will try to put the top rows and bottom rows in both columns on the same level.  If you don't want that, you can add `\raggedcolumns` to your file.

[image: output]